# Toggle class when checkbox is checked with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a switcher made with bootstrap, i want that when the checkbox (switch) is checked, the `class` of the panel change, from grey to green. I did this before but i changed my switcher and it doesn't work anymore.

The main markup of the switcher is this:

```
<label class="switch-light well" onclick="">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>
    Wireless
    <span>Off</span>
    <span>On</span>
  </span>

  <a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
</label>
```

And the toggleclass of JQuery is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.switch-light').bootstrapSwitch();
    $('.switch-light').on('input:checked', function () {
        $("#tasksList > div > div.panel").toggleClass("panel-off2 panel-off", this.checked).toggleClass("panel-success", !this.checked);
    }).change()
});
```

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CYLcY/

Comment: Could you please provide a more simplified example of your problem in the JSFiddle?

Comment: I'm amazed on('input:checked' ... would work ??? you need to use on('change', input ...

Comment: Before i used switchChange.bootstrapSwitch instead input:checked but it doesn't work...

Comment: @C-link is most certainly right, that selector definitely does not work. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wkJ77/

Comment: In your fiddle is too many errors, bad JS linking and so on. Try to simplify your fiddle.

Comment: Yeah i know but i don't know what i need to do...

Comment: Try this instead http://jsfiddle.net/jtrunecek/wkJ77/1/

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work with my switcher...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this code:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.switch-light').bootstrapSwitch();
    $('.panel-body input').on('change', function() {
        $(this).parents('.panel-body').prev().parent('.panel').toggleClass("panel-off2", !this.checked).toggleClass("panel-success", this.checked);
    })
});

Also you can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/CYLcY/27/.
```

Comment: Doesn't work... The only variable that change the switcher is the input checkbox.

Comment: You want when the slider is set to ON all the headers task should be green?

Comment: When the checkbox (that have an opacity 0, so it doesn't show), is checked, the #tasksList > div > div.panel it's going to toggle class "panel-success" to show the panel green, and when is unchecked it's toggle class to "panel-off2 panel-off" to show grey.

Comment: In the JSFiddle it's works but when i replace the JS lines in my site it doesn't work, you changed only the JS lines or HTML and CSS too?

Comment: On your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/CYLcY/ you have two javascript errors: 1) $ is undefined which means that you didn't put the jquery code you can added with:  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 2) $(...).bootstrapSwitch is not an function which means you didn't add the js file for this, the js file you can find it here: http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/ named: bootstrap-switch.js, so if you will include this it will work

Comment: On my example: http://jsfiddle.net/CYLcY/28/ you can see that on body I add this javascript and it works.

Comment: I added all your scripts on my site (is a local site so i can't show you online) and it throws me an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function, so it's doesn't work, the panels don't show green or grey when i activate or deactivate the switcher

Comment: I did my best Pedro, so you are on your own from now on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try again this:

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.switch-light').bootstrapSwitch();
    $('.switch-light input').on('change', function() {
        $('.panel').toggleClass("panel-off2", !this.checked).toggleClass("panel-success", this.checked);
    })
});

Also check the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/CYLcY/28/.
```